# PIC Microcontroller to PC via Usart

Tags: pic, usart

I have designed a temperature monitoring device and am wanting to send the data recorded to my PC. I am having issues sending data from my PIC18F252 to my PC via Usart (Purchased a USB 2.0 to TTL UART 6PIN CP2102 Module Serial Converter). I could not see any data being transferred when i used putty so decided to run tests using a serial connector (direct on to my board pins) to see if the data I am inputting is the same that is being received, now this is where I find the issue that the data received is garbage and not want I would imagine to see (so it is sending some data). The data is sent when I press the download switch.

Also when I run the program on MPLAB I can see the data on the registers being stored as they should be, so am assuming it is to do with my [send data code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7CXv.png)

I have also within the program set the baud rate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

**;TX DATA TO PC**

SEND_DATA (this is called when the download button is pressed)

```
BCF     INTCON,GIE ; Stop Int
MOVF    MAX_DAYS,W
CALL    TXIT
MOVF    FSR0H,W
CALL    TXIT
MOVF    FSR0L,W
CALL    TXIT
MOVLW   01H
MOVWF   FSR1H
CLRF    FSR1L
```

TX_LOOP

```
MOVF    POSTINC1,W
CALL    TXIT
MOVLW   06H
XORWF   FSR1H,W
BTFSS   STATUS,Z
GOTO    TX_LOOP
BSF     INTCON,GIE ; Restart Int
RETURN
```

TXIT

```
MOVWF   TXREG
BTFSS   TXSTA,TRMT
GOTO    $-1
RETURN
```

**;SETUP USART FOR TX**

```
MOVLW   B'00100100'
MOVWF   TXSTA
MOVLW   B'10000000' 
MOVWF   RCSTA
MOVLW   .23
MOVWF   SPBRG
```

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question as plain text, not in screenshots.

Comment: You probably have a timing issue, whether the CPU speed, or the baudrate calculation. There are several source clock and scale down register to check.